# Refresh an element only on page load and call on a function in javascript , jquery , ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just want to update the `#task` div only on page load and when I call it on another function (Like `on click a button`). But in my code it is constantly refreshing the div because of `setInterval()` function.

Here is my Code

```js
// FETCH ALL TASKS
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>alltasks',
    data: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
    $("#tasks").append(data);
    }
  })
});       
        
// REFRESH THE TASK AREA EVERY 2S
$(setInterval(function() {
  $('#task').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>alltasks");
}, 2000))
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: I don’t get what the issue is. Remove the set timeout and add the onclick event handler..:

Comment: okay and on the page load?

Comment: something like that?https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="tasks"></div>
<button onclick="readTasks()">Read Tasks</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function readTasks(){
    $('#task').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>alltasks");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    readTasks();
});
```

Make sure that you load Javascript at the footer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro 